# Solving the equivalent congruence I found and using it to derive the solution to the original congruence (elementary number theory)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, primitive-roots

I am trying to solve following problem. I have done the entire problem, so I'm not asking anyone to do the problem for me. But I need some confirmation on whether or not the very last part of my argument is valid.

***Problem***: Write an xy-table for $y ≡ (−2)^x$ mod $23
$ to verify $−2$ is a primitive root. Using the substitution $u ≡ (−2)^x$ mod $23$, rewrite the congruence $11u^7 ≡ 1$ mod $23$ as an equivalent congruence of the form $ax + b ≡ 0$ mod $n$.
Then, solve the equivalent congruence you found and use it to derive the solution to
the original congruence $11u^7$ ≡ $1$ mod $23$.

First, I had no trouble creating the table, nor any difficulty arguing that $-2$ is a primitive root. Then, when I rewrote the congruence $11u^7 ≡ 1$ mod $23$, and using the given substitution, I found that $91x + 9 ≡ 0$ mod $22$.

Finally, I determined that $91x + 9 ≡ 0$ mod $22$ can be simplified down to $x ≡ 19$ mod $22$.

**Everything below this bolded text is where asking whether or not my argument is valid and legitimate:**

I said that $x ≡ 19$ mod $22$, which implies that $x ≡ 19$ mod $23$.
Thus, $u ≡ (-2)^{19} ≡ 20$ mod $23$.
EDIT: Thanks to Bill Dubuque, I realized this implication is completely wrong!

If someone could verify the validity of this last step, that would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: $x=41$ defies this no ?

Comment: $\!\bmod 23:\ u^{\Large 7}\equiv (-2)^{\Large \color{#c00}{7x}} \equiv  1/11 \equiv -22/11 \equiv -2^{\Large\color{#c00}1}\!\iff \bmod 22\!:\  \color{#c00}{7x\equiv 1}\equiv -21\iff x\equiv -3.\ $ To check your work we need to see the details om how you "rewrote the congruence".

Comment: "which implies that $x\equiv 19\bmod 23$" is incorrect and unneeded (but maybe it is just an editing error).

Comment: @BillDubuque Thank you for pointing that out. Indeed, that implication was extremely wrong and illegal.

Comment: We used $\bmod 23\!:\ {\rm ord}(-2)=22\Rightarrow (-2)^x\equiv (-2)^y\iff x\equiv y\pmod{22}\,$ by [mod order reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033681/242). Thus $\bmod 22\!:\ x\equiv -3\,\Rightarrow \bmod 23\!:\ u\equiv (-2)^{-3}\equiv 1/(-8)\equiv 24/(-8)\equiv -3.\ $

Comment: Thank you! That helps significantly, and the post you linked and wrote is extremely good.

Comment: Order of $(-2)$ is 11 if you wanted to save time.